# Use Objects as Primary keys and Composite keys in JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I want to know whetheris it a **GOOD** practise to use Objects as composite keys in JPA. For example I have few composite keys and the are foreign keys from another tables and mapped with them.

**Composite Class**

```
@Embeddable
public class CashInstrumentComposite implements Serializable {


  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6065538857637001219L;

  @Column(name = "instrument_id", nullable = false)
  private String instrumentId;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
  private Company companyId;

  @Column(name = "instrument_type", nullable = true)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private InstrumentType instrumentType;

  @Column(name = "batch_no", nullable = false)
  private String batchNumber;
}
```

**Entity Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bank_corporate_cash_instrument")
public class CashInstrument extends Model {

/* serial version id. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8360452197690274885L;

/* specify the composite key */
@EmbeddedId
private CashInstrumentComposite compositeId;
```

I can persist using this without any problem, BUT I read this,

> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqf

It says there that primarykey should be one of

- Java primitive types
- Java primitive wrapper types
- java.lang.String
- java.util.Date (the temporal type should be DATE)
- java.sql.Date
- java.math.BigDecimal
- java.math.BigInteger

So what did I do wrong here? Please explain.Thank You

Comment: I don't understand, you used a `String` as your ID and in the list you linked it says you may use a `String`

Comment: It is, have a look at '@EmbeddedId' and '@Embedded'

Comment: @j.con above class is my composite class, there are 4 keys bind as a composite

Comment: @maress thats what I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did some sample apps I looks like I can use objects as composite keys. But I'm still confuse about whats written in this documentation

> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqf

But it's not a good practice to use composite keys because when u use one of the key in the composite key as a foreign key, then you have to duplicate the rest of the keys in that composite also. This is a waste specially if you have 4-5 keys as a composite.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have not interpreted what that piece of documentation says correctly:

> The primary key, **or the property or field of a composite primary key**, must be one of the following Java language types:

Answer (score 0):

@EmbeddedId from javadoc

Is applied to a persistent field or property of an entity class or mapped superclass to denote a composite primary key that is an embeddable class. The embeddable class must be annotated as Embeddable.
    Example:

```
@EmbeddedId
protected EmployeePK empPK;
```

And the EmployeeKey:

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeePK {
 private Long key1;
 private Long key2;
}
```

You can have a look at:

[Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqf)

Comment: I did as follw, what my concern is inside the EmployeePK, can I give my own object as a key??

Comment: Yes, you can, if it follows some convention as mentioned in that particular section of the doc:

Comment: But in that doc it syas I can use primary keys should be Java primitive types,
Java primitive wrapper types, etc.
No mention about my own object class...